# Spring - migrate from DAO-Service architecture to JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-orm

I have web MVC written using Spring. I used separate dao and service classes.

My old code:

```
@Repository
public class RoleDaoImpl implements RoleDao {
...
}

@Service
@Transactional
public class RoleManagerImpl implements RoleManager {
...
}

@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @Autowired
    private RoleManager roleManager;
...
}
```

Now I would like to try Spring JPA. But I can't rewrite my testing project from dao-service to Spring JPA.

**There is project source on github https://github.com/martin159/springjpa**

After I run project I get following error:

```
WARN : org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1568)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:540)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:956)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:747)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:634)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:671)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1840)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No PersistenceProvider specified in EntityManagerFactory configuration, and chosen PersistenceUnitInfo does not specify a provider class name either
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:323)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1627)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1564)
    ... 25 more
ERROR: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
```

I spend a lot of hours with Spring JPA, but I still can't to fix it.

Do you have any idea what I do bad?

Comment: The code in your github repository has nothing to do with Spring Data JPA but just JPA. Your JPA configuration is wrong as you haven't specified which provider to use. Neither in your `persistence.xml` nor in your configuration of the `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactory`. Finally you want to add the configuration parts to your question as it isn't really nice to expect from people to scan your github repository.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is because you specified `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` without telling spring what's your persistence unit name is. Hence Spring will use the default one.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
```

Meanwhile in persistence.xml, you specified your persistence unit name is `springjpa`

```
<persistence-unit name="springjpa" transaction-type="JTA">
```

Try

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="springjpa"/>
</bean>
```